# How to properly reset 1 ambiguity state of a LS filter when a new sensor is being read?

Tags: kalman-filter

I am using a least squares filter with multiple states coming in per epoch of time.

I have up to 100 sensors available.  But only 10 are usually active at any given epoch.  So I am resolving roughly 10 ambiguities.  When a new senor comes on line, how do I properly integrate it?